# ValueError using Sympy.diffgeom when using metric_to_* functions

Tags: python, sympy

I am getting the following error when I try to use the `sympy.diffgeom` library:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy-0.7.7.dev0-
py2.7.egg/sympy/diffgeom/diffgeom.py", line 1463, in twoform_to_matrix
raise ValueError('The input expression concerns more than one '

ValueError: The input expression concerns more than one coordinate systems, 
hence there is no unambiguous way to choose a coordinate system for the 
matrix.
```

The coordinate system is defined as

```
CoordSystem(egg_carton, Patch(P, Manifold(M, 2)), (u, v))
```

and the metric in two-form is as following

```
metric = (sin(v)**2*sin(u)**2 + 1)*TensorProduct(dv, dv) + (cos(v)**2*cos(u)**2 + 1)*TensorProduct(du, du) + (-cos(2*v - 2*u)/8 + cos(2*v + 2*u)/8)*TensorProduct(du, dv) + (-cos(2*v - 2*u)/8 + cos(2*v + 2*u)/8)*TensorProduct(dv, du)
```

The following code

```
print type(metric)
print type(u)
print type(v)
print type(du)
print type(dv)
```

results in the following output

```
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> 
<class 'sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.BaseScalarField'> 
<class 'sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.BaseScalarField'> 
<class 'sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.Differential'> 
<class 'sympy.diffgeom.diffgeom.Differential'>
```

When I try to use this metric as argument to any of the following functions

```
sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_Christoffel_1st
sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_Christoffel_2nd
sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_Ricci_components
sympy.diffgeom.metric_to_Riemann_components
```

I get the ValueError. What seems to be the problem here ?

**Edit 1 :**

I have also posted this question on the [Sympy google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/3Dn8iPaezXQ).

**Edit 2 :**

If I simply hard code each metric, every thing works properly. For example, take egg carton surface as an example,

```
from sympy.diffgeom import Manifold, Patch, CoordSystem, TensorProduct
from sympy import sin,cos
dim = 2
m = Manifold("M",dim)
patch = Patch("P",m)
system = CoordSystem('egg_carton', patch, ["u", "v"])
u,v = system.coord_functions()
du,dv = system.base_oneforms()
metric = (sin(v)**2*sin(u)**2 + 1)*TensorProduct(dv, dv) +\
         (cos(v)**2*cos(u)**2 + 1)*TensorProduct(du, du) +\
         (-cos(2*v - 2*u)/8 + cos(2*v + 2*u)/8)*TensorProduct(du, dv) +\
         (-cos(2*v - 2*u)/8 + cos(2*v + 2*u)/8)*TensorProduct(dv, du)
```

I can use any of the metric_to_* functions without getting the ValueError.

Also, here is the `sympy.srepr` output for `u` and `du` respectively:

```
BaseScalarField(CoordSystem(Symbol('egg_carton'), Patch(Symbol('P'), Manifold(Symbol('M'), Integer(2))), Tuple(Symbol('u'), Symbol('v'))), Integer(0))

Differential(BaseScalarField(CoordSystem(Symbol('egg_carton'), Patch(Symbol('P'), Manifold(Symbol('M'), Integer(2))), Tuple(Symbol('u'), Symbol('v'))), Integer(0)))
```